# Object Values not setting

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, object, custom-object

I am having issues with the code below. The date values are not being set to the `todayObj`. The `dateNow` prints correctly and passes to the `getTodayStepsandKJ` method correctly, which returns the correct data in the array. But all of the date fields in the object are nil:

```
func checkCurrentSteps(){
    let dateNow = Date()
    print("Date Now")
    print(dateNow)
    todayObjManager.sharedInstance.getTodayStepsAndKJ(dayForCalc: dateNow) { arrayData in
        self.todayObj.steps = arrayData[0]
        self.todayObj.kJ = arrayData[1]
        self.todayObj.Date = dateNow
        self.todayObj.DateSteps = dateNow
        self.todayObj.DateKj = dateNow
        self.startListeners()
        todayObjManager.sharedInstance.saveTodayCloud(dayObj: self.todayObj)
    }   
}
```

Comment: Does the closure even execute? Try putting a `print` within the closure

Comment: Your problem isn't in this code.  How are those fields declared in the object (By the way, they should start with a lower case d).  Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through with the debugger to see what is happening?  Is `dateNow` `nil` in the closure (not likely).  Is the assignment failing or is it `nil` when you fetch the data back from being saved.  Also, I get worried when I see a values being assigned to a property in an asynchronous closure; Are you perhaps accessing them elsewhere *before they have been set*?

Comment: The closure is executing.

Comment: The values are not being used until passed into the method at the end of the closure. I added a break point

Comment: Please provide more information on where/when you are seeing the values as `nil` - Is it in the closure? Somewhere else?  What does the debugger show when you step through the closure code?

Comment: If that is the case then I can't see a good reason for using a property (`self.todayObj`) rather than a local variable inside the closure.  BY using a local variable you manage scope and eliminate the possibility of accessing the property before the values are set

Comment: They are nil in the next method and any other time I try to read them after the code is complete, I have added a break point and stepped through line by line and the values are always nil.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215056/discussion-between-paulw11-and-joffd).